# jar files for uploading and downloading files

Tags: spring

Is there any jar file available for uploading and downloading files in spring framework.Am searching for one to which we can pass our selected files then it can upload the files to server location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Spring's multipart (fileupload) support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s08.html):

> Spring has built-in multipart support to handle fileuploads in web applications. The design for the multipart support is done with pluggable MultipartResolver objects, defined in the org.springframework.web.multipart package. Out of the box, Spring provides a MultipartResolver for use with Commons FileUpload (http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/fileupload). How uploading files is supported will be described in the rest of this chapter.

It explains everything you need for file upload, hope that helps.